# Python: How to type-hint a class variable?

Tags: python

Yes, I'm aware of the `Enum` class but I'm not interested in using it.

This is my Class enum:

```py
class SomeClass:
    SOME_STRING = "regular"
    SOME_STRING2 = "important"
    SOME_STRING3 = "accounts"
    SOME_STRING4 = "special"
```

This is my type-hinted function:

```py
def do_something(*, queue_name: SomeClass):
    #....
```

And when I call it like this:

```py
purge_queue(queue_name=SomeClass.SOME_STRING)
```

I get a warning:

> Argument of type 'Literal['regular']' cannot be assigned to parameter 'queue_name' of type 'SomeClass'
>     'str' is incompatible with 'SomeClass'

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why do you want the type annotation to have anything to do with `SomeClass`? It sounds like it should just be `str`.

Comment: If you want to ensure that the input is one of `SomeClass`'s class variables, well, "one of `SomeClass`'s class variables" isn't a type.

Comment: @user2357112 - I want the actual value passed to be one of the `SomeClass`'s defined values. I know type-hints aren't meant to enforce *values*, but can they not be used to enforce type? (in this case, `SOME_STRING`s are "members" of `SomeClass`)

Comment: Your notion of "membership" is not how the type system works.

Comment: @user2357112 - fair enough. Thanks for answering.

Comment: Why are you rejecting `Enum`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A type hint of `SomeClass` means that values should be instances of `SomeClass`, not class variables of `SomeClass`. "One of `SomeClass`'s class variables" isn't a type, and there is no annotation you can use with that meaning.

The stdlib solution for this kind of thing is `enum.Enum`, but you've rejected that. In that case, the next best thing is the [`typing.Literal`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Literal) type, introduced in Python 3.8. With that, you can write things like

```
SomeClassValue = typing.Literal['regular', 'important', 'accounts', 'special']

def do_something(*, queue_name: SomeClassValue):
    ...
```

You *cannot* somehow pull the type parameters from the class variables of `SomeClass`; it might run, but it won't type-check. This means you'll have to have a lot of error-prone code duplication if you go down this route. (Also, you'll probably need to put [`Final`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Final) annotations on your class variables, to indicate they're not supposed to be reassigned.)